# PHP/mysql: Como deshabilitar botón si un accesorio de la BD se agota

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, sql, condiciones

Tengo una base de datos de una tienda de accesorios, y me gustaría que el botón de 'añadir al carrito' de mi aplicación se desactive, es decir, que no se pueda hacer click en él cuando el producto no tiene más unidades de las veces clickeadas, como en este caso 3. El codigoExist pertenece a la tabla denominada 'existencias', y está relacionado con el codigoAcc de la tabla 'accesorios'.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**SQL.php:**

```
public static function agotado($ce){
        $query="select * from existencias where codigoExist='$ce' and unidadesExist<";
        $resultado=self::ejecutaConsulta($sql);
        $agotado=null;       
        if(isset($resultado)) {
            $row = $resultado->fetch();
            $agotado=new Accesorios($row);
        }      
        return $agotado;      
    }
```

**accesorios.php:**

```
if($accesorios['']<){
        echo "<input id='botones' type='disabled' name='enviar' value='Añadir al carrito'/><br><br>";
        echo "</form>"; 
        echo "</p>";
            }else{
                echo "<input id='botones' type='button' name='enviar' value='Añadir al carrito'/><br><br>";
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

El atributo disabled se usa sobre la etiqueta como atributo independiente, tu lo estas usando como valor del atributo type. prueba lo siguiente

```
echo "<input id='botones' type='button' disabled name='enviar' value='Añadir al carrito'/><br><br>";
```

Debería funcionar siempre y cuando tu consulta y condicional sean correctas.

Ejemplo del uso de disabled.

```css
.boton-habilitado{
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  color:green;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.boton-deshabilitadp{
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  color:red;
  cursor:not-drop;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="boton habilitado" class="boton-habilitado"></input> <br><br>

<input type="button" disabled value="boton deshabilitado" class="boton-deshabilitado"></input>
```

Comment: De acuerdo luisam, creo no obstante que los problemas principales los estoy teniendo con la consulta y el condicional, ya que no se si está bien enfocado. ¿Me podría orientar un poco y decirme si está bien encaminado? Perdone las molestias.

Comment: Si claro, revisando al parecer si hay un problema, pero ahora mismo estoy ocupado por hoy, si esperas a mañana con gusto te ayudo.

Comment: Muchas gracias!